# Can not generate probability for Monte Carlo Simulation in python 3.x?

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

I have created a high-level Python random function for a Monte Carlo Simulation in python and my code is running correctly. However, I'm not able to generate a probability to draw: 2 - blue and 2 - purple balls out of 40 balls from a hat. Total balls are 40, 10-red, 10-blue, 10-Yellow, 10-Purple. Following is my code:

```
import numpy as np
RED, BLUE, YELLOW, PURPLE = 1,2,3,4

def create_hat_of_balls(N):
    hat = 10*['1'] + 10*['2'] + 10*['3'] + 10*['4']
    val = 0 
    for num in range(40):
        drawing = [random.choice(hat) for num in range(10)]
        prob = drawing.count('blue') == 2 and drawing.count('purple') == 2
    val += prob
    final_prob = val / N
    print(f"(Blue, Purple) probability: {100*final_prob}%") 
    return hat

hat = create_hat_of_balls(10)
print(hat)
```

**Result**

```
(Blue, Purple) probability: 0.0%
['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', 
'2', '2', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', 
'4', '4', '4', '4']
```

How my probability is 0.0% ?

Much appreciating for help.

Comment: Why would `drawing` contain any instances of `'blue'` or `'purple'` when `hat` contains only the strings `'1', '2', '3', '4'`?

Comment: By the way, you are sampling with replacement, but you may have intended to sample without replacement.

Comment: @kaya3 You are right for the first comment but I'm generating count to get the probability and on the top of code I have assigned integer values to each color. In this case, what do I have to do?

Comment: @kaya3 I don't see any connection between sampling with replacement and getting count to get the probability !!! I did sampling because of my professor recommended it to me.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is trying to represent colours in three different ways:

- As numbers `1, 2, 3, 4`
- As strings `'1', '2', '3', '4'`
- As strings `'blue', 'purple'`

The problem is that when you do `drawing.count('purple')` it returns 0, because `drawing` doesn't contain any instances of the string `'purple'` - it contains strings like `'4'`, because that's what you put in `hat`.

You should choose one representation, and stick with it.

```py
import numpy as np
RED, BLUE, YELLOW, PURPLE = 1, 2, 3, 4

def create_hat_of_balls(N):
    hat = [RED, BLUE, YELLOW, PURPLE] * 10
    val = 0 
    for num in range(40):
        drawing = [random.choice(hat) for num in range(10)]
        prob = drawing.count(BLUE) == 2 and drawing.count(PURPLE) == 2
        val += prob
    final_prob = val / N
    print(f"(Blue, Purple) probability: {100*final_prob}%") 
    return hat

hat = create_hat_of_balls(10)
print(hat)
```

I also fixed the indentation on the line `val += prob` - you should do this inside the loop to accumulate results from each sampling, instead of just the last one.

There are still other logical problems with your code - you are only using `N` to divide at the end, and there are some hard-coded instances of `10` in your function but I'm not sure which one(s) should be changed to `N`, and maybe the `40` should depend on `N` somehow too.

Comment: I have changed `drawing.count('BLUE') == 2 and drawing.count('Purple') == 2` to `drawing.count(2) == 2 and drawing.count(4) == 2` and from `hat = 10*['1'] + 10*['2'] + 10*['3'] + 10*['4']` to `hat = 10*[1] + 10*[2] + 10*[3] + 10*[4]` . This worked with me. Thank you for your time and clarification in the code.